# Set DatePicker calendar cell color on selectable dates only

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Looking for the proper way to set the cell color of the selectable dates in my custom calendar - don't seem to be able to find any post to support this. second property in the `true/false,css,mouseover` properties has very little support on this topic. See my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeffbarclay/6qb763wg/)

```
A function that takes a date as a parameter and must return an array with:
[0]: true/false indicating whether or not this date is selectable
[1]: a CSS class name to add to the date's cell or "" for the default presentation
[2]: an optional popup tooltip for this date
The function is called for each day in the datepicker before it is displayed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just fine.  The problem is that your CSS is being overridden by CSS with more [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).  In other words, some CSS in the DatePicker library is trumping yours.  To fix this, you can add `!important` to your `.red` CSS properties, like this:

```
.red2 {
    color: green !important;
}
```

**But, this is a heavy-handed fix.**  A better solution is to be more specific with your CSS selector, by adding `.ui-datepicker-calendar`:

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar .red2 {
     color: green;  // etc, etc
}
```

This will make sure your CSS more specific, so it will take precedence over the built-in CSS.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/og2o3ob1/

The other observation is that some of the properties you want to modify are actually in the `<a>` elements.  To make sure you modify the text color for instance, you will probably need to specifically target the `<a>` elements:

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar .red2 a {
     color: green;  // etc, etc
}
```

Comment: where are you adding `!important` ?

Comment: I'm not.  My point was you could add `!important` to every attribute: `color: green !important;`, but this is not the best solution.  The better solution is to make your selector more specific.  In other words, adding `.ui-datepicker-calendar` to your selector makes it more specific, so it will take precedence over the built-in CSS.  If this doesn't make sense, read the link about `specificity` in the answer.

Comment: thanks  - got it, one last thing, on you Fiddle the center is still black? how can I make that colored? - looks like a png from the properties inspector? within td a - but I'm not too good with css

Comment: You need to change the `background` of `.ui-datepicker-calendar .red2 a`.  Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/og2o3ob1/1/